# Adding elements to arrays via indexes, increments?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

Hey something I just found out by accident that's going to save me a lot of work provided there are no side effects, is that lets say you have this file

```
0
0
0
```

And you need to add numbers to it, sort of like a tally, but you also want to modify specific characters in the string, instead of adding them....but you want to add to the end instead of modifying any non-existant indices...

So if you take one of those lines above, and use str_split on it, then try to add something via a numbered index, it seems to not get confused!

Like say I want to modify the 20th index of line 2 of that file. Since there is no 20th index it will just automatically add the element to the end of the array.

Can I just let this slide or might this be risky to just let it do this? Like a side effect I'm not aware of or something....

Man if there was ever any of my questions to get closed because they didn't understand what I was asking.... :P

Sorry but I can't think of how else to word it.

Ok here's some code

```
$change_str = str_split($array_change[$list_num]);
UltraDB($change_str, "Change String BEFORE");
$change_str[20] = '5';
$array_change[$list_num] = implode('', $change_str);
foreach($array_change as $v){
file_put_contents("file.txt", $v . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
UltraDB($array_change, "File is now.");
```

UltraDB is just my debugging function combining var_dump echoing and line breaks

EDIT: Ok just thought how to word my question better: When an index doesn't exist in an array made from str_split, but you want to add a certain index of that array, if that index doesn't yet exist, is it normal for it just to add what you're adding to an end index instead?

Comment: *Sorry but I can't think of how else to word it.* Show some code! Sorry, but I have no idea what you are up to.

Comment: So this is what I think you're trying to say, correct me if I'm wrong. You are trying to read IN the lines of a file until X is hit (X is 20 in your example) them you are trying to read OUT that line until Y (you never listed Y, but lets say its 10) Y can either be character length or read by a delimiter (like tab, or comma or something) at that point of X&Y you want to alter that value (Z). If that value doesn't exist (Count of Y doesn't exist) you want to append a NEW LINE for the value of Z.... Right?

Comment: Hi ehime thanks for your code, however I'm not looking for a code, I'm just wondering if the principle I THINK I understand is correct, or if it's just a fluke. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand it properly, but here is how you can edit the 20th line safely without any needed values just by the line number:

```
$file = file('file.txt');
$file[19] = $file[19]++; // the index starts with so for line 20 we take index 19

// and saving it
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $file));
```

Answer (score 0):

The above was confusing but I think this is what you're asking. Untested so yeah... whatever...

```
$d=' '; //delimiter

$x=20;  //how many lines in
$y=10;  //how many values out
$z=4;   //value to insert at X/Y

$file = file('file.txt');
$tmp = explode($d, $file[$x]);

if($file[$y]) {
    $file[$y]=$z;
} else {
    $file[]=$z;
}

foreach($file as &$line){
    $line = implode($d, $line);
}

file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $file));
```